# How to add facebook's new comment system to blogger?

Tags: xml, facebook, comments, blogger

Have you been to techcrunch and used the new facebook commenting setup?  Basically that is what I am looking to do on blogger.  I am running into a problem where I have the comment system working but instead of having a unique commenting feed for each post; you get one single global feed that combines all the comments from all the posts into one giant feed.  I think I confused myself.

Post A 
http://www.igebadia.com/2011/03/i-am-only-guy-on-youtube-who-did.html

post B
http://www.igebadia.com/2010/11/manliest-cat-ever.html

I don't know much about xml which is how blogger does things apparently.  I am more of a copy and paste hack with no real skills what so ever. I am a new user so I can't post the code it seems so if you source the page and then search for fb-root you should see what I have done.  It is showing one giant feed across my blogger site. I want a new one for each blog post.

any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...

In the FB code you have a href='YOUR-URL'. Replace this with expr:href='data:post.url'.  And it will work!

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully placed it on my site http://fun.vidort.com, but if you are migrating then put "migrated=1", else it will show old facebook comment system